# prevent a list in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm working in Rmarkdown and knitting to PDF. I want to start a paragraph with `(a)` ***without*** creating a list. Adding `\(a)` works, but it highlights the rest of my Rmd file text, making it hard to read. Is there another way to indicate that I do not want to create a list in Rmarkdown?

[image]

[image]

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---

This is the first paragraph.

```{r, include=FALSE}
1+1 # nice highlighting before problem
```

(a) This should be the second paragraph. (b) But it is interpreted as a list.

\(a) This slash works to keep the text as a paragraph, but it highlights all remaining text in my Rmd file, which makes it hard to read. (b) Is there another method to use (a) without creating a list?

Here is a good list, but still wrong color in Rmd:

(a) One
(b) Two

```{r, include=FALSE}
1+1 # bad highlighting after problem
```
````

Comment: `\(a\)` seems to turn `a` into a special character

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer could you tell me what your default text encoding setting is `(Prefs>Code>Saving)`? Maybe we have a different RStudio setup.

Comment: It is UTF-8  ...

Comment: I was wrong. Reloading the pdf showed it didnt work afterall...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting (a) in `<span>` like

```
<span> (a) </span> This should be the second paragraph.
```

It's a bit hacky but it works for html & pdf and it fixes the highlighting problem.

Comment: well, it works. and for such an uncommon use case, i think it works just fine. i'll leave this open for a bit to see if there are other fixes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the  element placing a `&nbsp;` on the previous line works. If there is actual text on the previous line then ending the line with two spaces also works.